# Printing the same content in all browsers

Tags: css, printing

I am building a web application that needs to print directly from browser, however, It should be very precise, right now I am using absolute positions and specifying left and top with pixels. How ever each browser prints in different places of the page, I also got different font sizes. How could I get same results?

Edit: this is a simple example of how I am publising the info. (text positions, will be dynamic, thats why are not in a css file)

http://juanefren.webfactional.com/file.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify [print style sheets](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/), however if it is absolutely essential that the printed version looks the same from all browsers your best bet is to skip attempting to print from the browser itself and output data as PDF from a server generated source.